# Merging data into DOCX fails using opentbs

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I've been using OpenTBS for the past year with PHP/MySQL to merge data into an MS Word DOCX document with no problems. I populate 2-3 large nested arrays as merge blocks and the resulting Word document is 50+ pages long. Performance has never been an issue.

Recently I seem to have reached some limit as the size of data to merge has increased. There are no errors when debugging, but I get a blank PHP page instead of downloading a DOCX file. Initially, I thought there may be some characters in the data that needed escaping, but that's not the case, and if I remove (any) 5 records from any sequence in the MySQL table used for the main merge block, it works again and I get a 60 page Word document downloaded.

I am currently using OpentTBS v1.9.8. Any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: OpenTBS desnot support

Comment: Sorry for previous comment. Could you check the same merging but with Show(OPENTBS_FILE) instead of Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD) so we can exclude any download problem ? My first idea is that you got a PHP error of allowed memory size which could be muzzled for some reason. This theory can be checked by increasing the memory limit.

Comment: Thanks @Skrol29 - increasing the PHP memory size appears to have resolved the problem.